# update method from crud operation in springboot reactive programming

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

this is roleDTo:

```
 @ApiModel(value = "RoleDto")
public class RoleDto {

    private UUID id;

    @NameValid
    private String name;

    private String description;
}
```

below is the update method from persistence layer.

```
public Mono updateRole(RoleDto roleDto) {
    return Mono.justOrEmpty(roleRepository.findById(roleDto.getId()))
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty())
            .flatMap(roleEntity -> {
                roleEntity.getName().equals(roleDto.getName());

                roleEntity.setId(roleDto.getId() == null ? roleEntity.getId() : roleDto.getId());
                roleEntity.setName(roleDto.getName() == null ? roleEntity.getName() : roleDto.getName());
                roleEntity.setDescription(roleDto.getDescription() == null ? roleEntity.getDescription() : roleDto.getDescription());
                return Mono.just(roleRepository.save(roleEntity));
            });
}
```

i want to add custom validation such that name should be unique.

i have written a custom validator for this as below.

```
public class NameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NameValid, String> {

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        // checking if name already exists in database
        RoleEntity roleEntity = roleRepository.findByName(s);
        if (roleEntity != null) {
            return false; // Name already exists, validation fails
        }

        return true; // Name is unique, validation passes
    }
}
```

this works if i try from postman to update a DTO and try to put name which already belongs to some other object, then it fails which is what is required.
however when i try to update a roleDto description without changing name ,still it fails.
which is not supposed to happen. i want the custom validator to ignore checking name for the dto which we are trying to update and check name for other objects in database.how do i go about it ?  any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could modify your validation to verify if input id is equal to the id of the object found by the validator ? Or just let the database do constraint validation (most SQL databases provide that feature)